# Can not deserialize appsettings IConfiguration section into array of typed elements

Tags: arrays, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, jsonserializer

I am trying to retrieve an IConfiguration section from my `appsettings.json` file which is an array of strongly typed elements and i keep getting an empty collection.
I am using whatever `Asp .Net Core 3.1` uses by default when deserializing the `IConfiguration` section:

(I am using `JsonSerializer` for all json specific tasks )

**DTO**

```
public class Element
{
   [JsonPropertyName("key")]
   public string Key {get;set;}
   [JsonPropertyName("value")]
   public string Value{get;set;}
}

public class Elements
{
   [JsonPropertyName("fields")]
   public IEnumerable<Element>Fields{get;set;}
}
public class Config
{
   [JsonPropertyName("elements")]
   public Elements Elements{get;set;}
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "config":{
    "fields":[
      {"key":"a","value":"aa"},
      {"key":"b","value":"bb"},
      {"key":"c","value":"cc"}
   }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            Config config=this.Configuration.GetSection("config").Get<Config>(); // elements count is 0
            Elements elements =  this.Configuration.GetSection("config:elements").Get<Elements>();  // elements count is 0
            
        }
}
```

I have tried :

- Changing my `IEnumerable` of typed elements (`Elements`) to `Array`,`List`,`IList` to no avail
- Placing my `Elements` field directly in the root to no avail

**P.S**
 If i change from `[SomeCollection]<Element>` to `[SomeCollection]<string>` it sees all the elements , so there is obviously a problem when deserializing collections of types.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `Elements` to `List<Element>`,here is a demo:

DTO:

```
public class Element
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }


    public class Config
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("fields")]
        public List<Element> Fields { get; set; }
    }
```

Startup:

```
Config config=this.Configuration.GetSection("config").Get<Config>();
```

**Update:**

Another way:

DTO:

```
public class Element
{
   [JsonPropertyName("key")]
   public string Key {get;set;}
   [JsonPropertyName("value")]
   public string Value{get;set;}
}

public class Elements
{
   [JsonPropertyName("fields")]
   public IEnumerable<Element>Fields{get;set;}
}
public class Config
{
   [JsonPropertyName("elements")]
   public Elements Elements{get;set;}
}
```

Startup:

```
Elements elements = this.Configuration.GetSection("config").Get<Elements>(); 
Config config= new Config { Elements = elements };
```

Comment: So you are implying that the only way to have a `Collection` of `Typed` objects in json is for it to be placed in the root of the json ?

Comment: I updated my answer with another way,you can get elements first,but you cannot get config with this.Configuration.GetSection("config").Get<Config>();,because your appsetting is not `{
    "config": {
      "elements": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "key": "a",
            "value": "aa"
          },
          {
            "key": "b",
            "value": "bb"
          },
          {
            "key": "c",
            "value": "cc"
          }
        ]
      }

    }
  }`